# Error in Opengl opencl interoperation

Tags: opengl, opencl

I get the following 4 errors after compiling.

```
error C2065: 'CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR' : undeclared identifier    
error C2065: 'CL_WGL_HDC_KHR' : undeclared identifier   
IntelliSense: identifier "CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR" is undefined   
IntelliSense: identifier "CL_WGL_HDC_KHR" is undefined
```

I use following headers:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
//#include <iostream> 
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <GL/glew.h> 
#ifdef MAC 
    #include <OpenCL/cl_gl.h> 
    #include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h> 
    #include <GLUT/freeglut.h> 
    #define GL_SHARING_EXTENSION "cl_APPLE_gl_sharing" 
#else 
    #include <CL/cl.h> 
    #include <CL/cl_gl.h> 
    #include <GL/glut.h>
```

Comment: I use following headers..#include <stdio.h>
//#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

#ifdef MAC
#include <OpenCL/cl_gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/freeglut.h>
#define GL_SHARING_EXTENSION "cl_APPLE_gl_sharing"

#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <CL/cl_gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

Comment: Try the following workaround until you can find why these declarations are missing (maybe an outdated header): "#define CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR 0x2008" and "#define CL_WGL_HDC_KHR 0x200B". See [this link](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetExtensionFunctionAddress.html) for more info.